# How to restore the missing component tree?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

My component tree is missing. But run app is normal. How can I restore the tree to normal? Invalidate caches cannot be restored.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rGoj.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try to see if split designer works or at least code section works. Check the problems tab in the bottom left corner. It should give sufficient information about the problem. Then we can work on it if you share with us.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: i think is windowds 10 defender.I forgot i chose yes
actious or delails.Your anti-virus program might be impacting your build performance. Android Studio checked the following directories.activity_main.xml ok.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think I will give him up and write again.